# which java library to use to modify a camera picture?

Tags: android, camera, image

I'm currently looking into creating an app that takes a picture using the phone's camera. The app will be used for clients that are pre-op for breast augmentation. The user will be able to take a picture of themselves then place two shperes over the picture, then with a slidebar manipulate the size of the spheres. This will give the user an idea which cup size they would like. I understand that there is something in photoshop that has the desired effect and this is what i'm trying to replicate but on the bitmap image.

Are there any suitable libraries out there that i can use. I'm looking into OpenGL as that is for 3D graphics.

Any ideas and input would be appreciated.

thanks Mat.

Answer (score 0):

Java does have it's own 2D and 3D APIs. Hopefully you can these to achieve your goal?